# What does ORRS r3,r3,r1 means when there is no Condition Code?

Tags: armv7

What I know only is that the 'S' in ORRS instruction is related to some condition code ? But where is the condition code in the instruction ?

If it should be there , how does the instruction will look like in that case ? And how does it will execute then ?

Comment: The S means only that the instruction *sets* the condition flags according to its result.  It doesn't use them otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

The S suffix is to specify whether this instruction should update the condition flags, rather than being conditional itself.

Page A7-337 of the Arm-V7m Architecture reference manual shows

[image]